# Error and incompatibility with crosstab (Postgresql-10)

Tags: postgresql, crosstab, postgresql-10

I'm trying to use the 'crosstab' function in Postgres 10 and it throws me the following error and I do not understand why:

*ERROR: return and sql tuple descriptions are incompatible
SQL state: 42601*

```
select * from crosstab
($$select xx, xxy, sum(t) as lala from po.zBORRARvi_intermedia
                           group by xx, xxy order by 1,2$$) as
ct("xx" varchar(255), "xy1" double precision, "xy2" double precision, "xy3" double precision, 
"xy4" double precision,"xy5" double precision, "xy6" double precision, "xy7" double precision,
   "xy8" double precision);
```

Answer (score 2):

the return type of the crosstab must be defined correctly, according to the number of expected columns.

Please read this [link](http://www.postgresql-archive.org/crosstab-help-td5511994.html)